# Regex to filter json value

Tags: json, regex, filter

Hello Guys i want to get just two value from a big json array using regular expression.
E.g: i have this json array

`'{"data":"1233","image":"dsfsdfsdfds"."text":"hello world"."name": "java"}'
'{"data":"1233df","image":"dsfsdfsdfsdfds"."text":"hello world"."name": "c#"}'
'{"data":"1233sds","image":"dsfsdferesdfds"."text":"hello world"."name": "python"}'
'{"data":"1sd233","image":"dsfsdfsdfrdfds"."text":"hello world"."name": "c++"}'`

I want to get text and name value from this array using regular expression

Comment: Don't use regex for this. [This is a FAQ.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags) (Structured formats like XML and JSON are like HTML in this context.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You **should not** use regex for parsing JSON. Instead parse JSON through inbuilt functions like `parse` in case you are using Javascript or different libraries like `GSON` in case you are using `JAVA`.

Still, if there is any special requirement to use Regex here, you can use below:

1) For text:

```
.*?text"\s?:\s?"([\w\s]+)
```

Output :

```
Group 1 - 'hello world'
```

2) For name

```
.*?name"\s?:\s?"([\w\s]+)
```

Output:

```
Group 1 - java
```

Demo: https://regex101.com/r/74hOO1/1

-- EDIT --

If you want both text and name in one regex, you can use below one, provided text always come before name:

```
.*?text"\s?:\s?"([\w\s]+).*?name"\s?:\s?"([\w\s]+)
```

Output:

```
Group 1.    46-57   `hello world`
Group 2.    68-72   `java`
```

Demo: https://regex101.com/r/74hOO1/2

Comment: i want them to be in one regular expresion. I mean that in one regular expression i can get text and name ... like every name and his text

Comment: not worked with my json format... can you see this (?:"name":")(.*?)(?:") and modified like what i am looking for ?

Comment: @Mohamed For the udpated json, I have updated regex as well :) You can check it at https://regex101.com/r/74hOO1/3

Answer (score 2):

```
var data = '{"data":"1233","image":"dsfsdfsdfds", "text":"hello world", "name": "java"}';

var parsedData = JSON.parse(data);

var text = parsedData.text;
var name = parsedData.name;
```

Comment: Mate +1 for efforts, but OP has not mentioned which language is being used

Comment: That is not solution with regex. @AmanChhabra can you explain how to use your solution in SQL?

Answer (score 0):

You can use this regex :

```
"name"\s?+:\s?+"?([\w+#\s]+)"?
```

to extract its value here name for example

if you want other key for example text use text instead of name

```
"text"\s?+:\s?+"?([\w+#\s]+)"?
```

you'll find the value of the key in the first group 
See here https://regex101.com/r/1ZSUph/1

Comment: i want one regular expression that show every name is the text behind